# what does allowName option for CEmailValidator mean?

Tags: php, yii, validation

what is 'allowName' option for in CEmailValidator?

what exactly do they mean by 'name'?

for example, let's say that I want to validate an email address that looks like abc@example.com.

is 'abc' the name part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, the name would be a person's "real name" like `"Fred Foobar <abc@example.com>"`
see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CEmailValidator#allowName-detail)